# how to remove parent element using php?

Tags: php

I want to get the HTML inside the parent element using php. For example, I have this structure:

```
                   <p>
                      <p>this is my first xml file </p>
                  </p>
```

and I want to get below text  as a result.

```
                  <p>this is my first xml file </p>
```

Comment: Your "result" has an error, as the trailing tag should be "</p>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of a DOM Parser

```
<?php
$html='<p>
                  <p>this is my first xml file </p>
              </p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag){
    if(!empty($tag->nodeValue)){ echo $tag->nodeValue;}
    }
```

Comment: directly we can call this one in php page ? $dom = new DOMDocument;

Comment: its deleting all p tags.i want to delte the parent tag only @Nagaraj S

Comment: yes its version problem .now i got result ... thank you a lot @ Nagaraj S